# How to compare dynamic url?

Tags: laravel

I have stored a url in session in laravel. Now i want to compare link between session url which was stored and the url()->previous(). But the problem is url is dynamic.

***THe problem i am facing***

```
    $url = url('/').'/complete-profile/*';
                if(session()->get('url.intended') == $url)
                {
                    return redirect('/home');
                }
```

This doesn't work. how to compare /complete-profile/* with other url.. (*) this can be anything

Comment: `session()->get('url.intended')` contains the full url path?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Builds your URL and the rest check if it contains the word `complete-profile` :

```
$url = 'complete-profile';
if (strpos(session()->get('url.intended'), $url) !== false) {
    return redirect('/home');
} else {
    //
}
```